# What is the best client side browser library to upload multiple files over http?

Tags: html, file-upload, uploading, multifile-uploader

What is the best client side http library to upload multiple files? If it can handle directories that's a huge bonus. I'm looking for something that is open source or free. I'm looking for something like FTP, but that works over http, through the browser. Uploading multiple files through a normal HTML 4.x form is a bit of a hassle when it comes to uploading more than 5-6 files.

Feel free to share your personal experiences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is also another great multiple file uploader. It was built off of SWFUpload and they added new features to it.

Some of the features that I have found most helpful are:

> The user can upload all the files at once using ctrl + clicking on all of
>   the files
>
> As the files are being downloaded a queue is displayed which
>   shows the files being downloaded including a completeion bar.
>
> As files are completed they are removed from the queue
>
> It also allows you to specify which file types the user is
>   able to download (they can only see the ones you choose)

Comment: Uploadify uses SWFUpload and requires Flash 9.0

Comment: I've used raw SWFUpload, browser uploading and looked into many options, Uploadify was by far the best.

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend something like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/) for that. It's main feature is its support for progress bars, but it also allows for queuing files which is particularly handy (this is actually the second time I've recommended it today).

Answer (score 8):

Just to make sure other options are documented (SWFUpload is great) - another good solution is [FancyUpload2](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/).

Comment: Right-on for documenting alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a Java based solution. I've been using [JumpLoader](http://jumploader.com/) on one of my web pages and haven't had any problems with it. It can also **upload directories**, which other solutions mentioned here do not support.

Comment: This actually looked pretty good compared to what I normally expect from Java web applications.

Answer (score 3):

Another option that I have used before is uploading and then extracting ZIP files. I have used [PEAR::Archive_Zip](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Zip) to extract. Requires more knowledge on the user's side, but supports directories and unlimited files (depending on the memory alloted to PHP).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [jquery-html5-upload](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-html5-upload/) it doesn't require Flash, and has a sexy jQuery API.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Dropzone.js is great for the job as it has a easy integration, it is open source, you can upload directories and there are many more functions. You can find more about it here https://www.dropzone.dev/