# Directory upload for Internet Explorer

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser

I'm using the webkitdirectory attribute on my page for allow the user to upload a whole directory:

```
<input webkitdirectory type="file" />
```

This works great for Chrome, Firefox and Edge, but is unsupported for Internet Explorer. Is there a alternative in order to support IE?

Comment: I don't know if this may help, but you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104990/chrome-folder-upload-api-detect-support-workaround-with-js-jquery) out.

Comment: its not officially supported in IE [See Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory)

Answer (score 2):

No, there will be no alternative if the browser itself does not support, as this is related to file system which javascript in webpage cannot reach.

One alternative is to use the `multiple` attribute to upload multiple files ([reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp)), but this still is only supported in IE10, and it won't keep the directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

Note these double meaning word from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt574730(v=vs.85).aspx)

> For compatibility purposes, Microsoft Edge supports the webkitdirectory attribute.

Which says that only Edge supports `webkitdirectory attribute`

See the link below to read about IE's `input` support

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535263(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the functionality is not supported in IE and therefore you can't use it. I tried finding a polyfill for it but without success.

After reading

> Non-standard This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

In the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory) website I wouldn't recommend you using this specific feature if you're developing anything but a test site for yourself.