# Upload HTML catalogs for a content type

Tags: html, drupal, upload, drupal-7

We have a couple of product catalogs which are interactive. This means that a vendor took our pages and created a nice "turn the page with the cursor" type of digital pager.

They sent this in a form of a static HTML page with `index.html` as an entry point and a lot of subdirectories. We have to host these static pages.

This kind of catalog digitalization might happen in the future and I created a new `Content Type` for it so maintainers of the site won't bother me to upload these things manually via FTP.

My problem is that this is a complete folder structure and not just 1 file.

**My question:** How can I "attach" a complete static HTML page structure in just one field of a Content Type? If it's not possible, how would you do it?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254251/what-is-the-best-way-to-upload-a-folder-to-a-website)

Comment: Related but I need something that is closer to drupal.

Comment: You can zip it and upload the zip to the content type field. but it would require much coding when you want to display the field on frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one file field for uploading compressed set of files (archive) there. Then use i.e. `hook_node_update()`

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7.x

to place your code which would unzip the archive in appropriate dir when ever node in your content type is updated.

http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php

or call shell command to unzip the archive...