# php multiple file upload script

Tags: php

Does anyone know of a good php or ajax multiple file upload script to upload to a web server?

The difference here is that nothing can be required on the client machine ie no flash!

I would like it to work just with the browser.

Comment: @Adam - this appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159600/multiple-file-upload, which has several good answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP multiple file uploads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542068/php-multiple-file-uploads)

Comment: This is probably the most frequently asked question of all on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

[digitarald’s fancy upload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form action="multiple_upload_ac.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td><strong>multiple Files Upload </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Select file
<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Select file
<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Select file
<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

STEP2: Create file multiple_upload_ac.php

```
<?php

//set where you want to store files
//in this example we keep file in folder upload
//$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name']; = upload file name
//for example upload file name cartoon.gif . $path will be upload/cartoon.gif

$path1= "upload/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][0];
$path2= "upload/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][1];
$path3= "upload/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][2];

//copy file to where you want to store file
copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0], $path1);
copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][1], $path2);
copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][2], $path3);

//$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'] = file name
//$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'] = file size
//$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type'] = type of file
echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][0]."<BR/>";
echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][0]."<BR/>";
echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type'][0]."<BR/>";
echo "<img src=\"$path1\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
echo "<P>";

echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][1]."<BR/>";
echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][1]."<BR/>";
echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type'][1]."<BR/>";
echo "<img src=\"$path2\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
echo "<P>";

echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][2]."<BR/>";
echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][2]."<BR/>";
echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type'][2]."<BR/>";
echo "<img src=\"$path3\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Use this code to display the error or success.

$filesize1=$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][0];
$filesize2=$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][1];
$filesize3=$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][2];

if($filesize1 && $filesize2 && $filesize3 != 0)
{
echo "We have recieved your files";
}

else {
echo "ERROR.....";
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////

// What files that have a problem? (if found)

if($filesize1==0) {
echo "There're something error in your first file";
echo "<BR />";
}

if($filesize2==0) {
echo "There're something error in your second file";
echo "<BR />";
}

if($filesize3==0) {
echo "There're something error in your third file";
echo "<BR />";
}
?>

I found this code in http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/2.html
for more details check <a href="http://www.specialend.com/">Tutorial</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

- [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/)
- [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your input - I've tried FancyUpload but it seems very complicated with little or no support for forums action

Comment: And what about SWFUpload? Same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) which support a wide variety of client technologies (html5, flash, silverlight, browserplus, gears) in addition to basic single file html4 upload, unlike SWFUpload which only does flash + html4 fallback.

It also integrates nicely with jQuery.