# Asynchronous web upload

Tags: php, asynchronous, lamp

Can anyone recommend a free module that will let me create web forms that allow asynchronous file uploads?  I want to be able to upload files on a website without doing a full page reload.   The module must work with a LAMP web site.  The module can be built in AJAX or Flash.

Or is it better for me to create this module myself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best client side browser library to upload multiple files over http?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159600/what-is-the-best-client-side-browser-library-to-upload-multiple-files-over-http)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are:

- a script such as [AJAX upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)
- a Flash file such as [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)
- a regular `form` with the `target` attribute pointing to an iframe on your page.

I prefer the Flash version since that makes it easier to add a progress bar.

Comment: You can't upload a file using AJAX. You'll have to use either an `<iframe>` or some Flash implementation.

Comment: @DouweM You're right, what I meant by "ajax" was really the iframe solution implemented with a script rather than pure html. It sort of acts like ajax eventhough it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use JQuery, try this
[plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)