# How can I upload a file?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I upload a file using Javascript?

Comment: More effort required on your part, describe the scenario and what do you need to acheive?  Browser based? What back-end server platform are you using?  Does the user get to select the file to be uploaded? Why Javascript and not a File input in HTML?

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/ydjq655

come on !

Comment: i want to upload file automatically as filename resides in an array of string.i am not using file input of html bcoz it ask for user input which we hv to it manually and i dont need that.

Comment: @Freshers: You *do* need the user to select the file. There is no way any (sane) browser would let you upload arbitrary files from the user's hard drive.

Comment: So any other way using php or ajax

Comment: PHP can't access the client. Ajax just means "Doing HTTP stuff with JS without leaving the page" so no.

Comment: If i provide predefine path then can i upload file without user input.

Comment: @fresher: no, you cant access the client hard disc throught javascript, and neither with php (as it is server-side). The user **must** be asket to select the file, then (after submitting the form), the browser send it to the server throught HTTP, where usually a server-side language take it and do whaterver he want ith it.

Comment: @Freshers - How about if I predefine the file as the standard path to a password file, or a Quicken database, or anything else that the user wouldn't want me to steal? Its impossible, and for good reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best client side browser library to upload multiple files over http?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159600/what-is-the-best-client-side-browser-library-to-upload-multiple-files-over-http)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean "In a browser" and "Without Flash/Java/Other plugins".

1. Have the user select a file using a file [input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) in a [form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html).
2. Call the [submit method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit) of the form object

e.g.

```
document.forms.myForm.submit();
```

If you want to do it without leaving the current page; set the [target](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#adef-target) of the form to an iframe.

Don't forget to set the [enctype](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype).

Comment: But that won't upload a file to the server

Comment: @mplacona - Yes, it will. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: ..did you forget to mention that javascript **cant** upload any file on the webserver, as it is client-side, and a server-side program language is required (php, python, ruby, whatever)?

Comment: @mplacona - if you go to a page written entirely in HTML being served just by apache select a file using a file input and click submit, the file is uploaded to the server.  I think what you mean is that a server side language is required to do something productive with the file.

Comment: @DaNiel - uploading means "sending the data somewhere", you **can** upload a file like this. Without a server side process to accept it, it will be received and then discarded. It will still be uploaded. Anything involving uploading or downloading will need a client **and** a server, I assumed the server component was obvious enough to not need an explicit mention. Incidentally, the server side process could be written in JavaScript, the programming language isn't exclusive to web browsers.

Comment: @David: yep, youre *technically* right, but its obvious that is the common sense (and im sure that is even for this question) for 'upload' to mean *send a file from user client to my server and save it* ;)

Answer (score 2):

**You can't** is the simple answer.

You could do it using a server-side language such as PHP, ColdFusion, ASP etc, and use Ajax to communicate with it and upload your file.

Here's a simple [PHP tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) and a [ColdFusion tutorial](http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Uploading-Files-in-ColdFusion/1710) as well

Hope the help you

Comment: While you can use Ajax, many people think of Ajax and XHR as being synonymous, but you can't use XHR for this, so you might want to be more explicit.

Comment: @mplacona using php can i automate this file uploading process.means i donot want that user browse for file upload.

Comment: But what file are you going to upload if you don't select it?

Comment: @mplacona i want to uplaod a pdf file

Comment: Yes, but won't the user have to select the file in order for it to be uploaded?

Comment: @Freshers: What if the file does not exists? How can you be sure that the user has this file?

Comment: Out of the box, you can't provide a predefined path. Also, As well as non-existing files, the path might be different from machine to machine, I.e. 62 bit machies will have two program files paths. Macs will have *nix paths and etc

Comment: perhaps this is now possible entirely in JS by using node.js

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to ask how to do it AJAX-style, i.e. without navigating away from the page, the answer lies in using `iframe`s. There are several examples of this if you google for it,  but here's one to get you started: http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html

The problem is that you can't upload a file via a regular AJAX form, so you have to make the browser submit the form properly. This is done by submitting the form in a hidden `iframe` instead.

Of course you should make sure the form works (though with a page refresh) when JavaScript is disabled. This is called "progressive enhancement" and is always a good idea.

The actual target of the form must of course be a script that is capable of handling the file upload, but this is true with JavaScript and without. JS being client-side, it can't (and shouldn't!) write to the server directly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the AJAX toolkit (google it) and look at the asyncrhonus file upload control. You should get the code in the page source for your browser.

However, it might be a better idea to use controls defined for this in the language you are using because javascript is browser dependant. The Javascript found within the page source of the toolkit page IS broswer dependant, but is generate on the fly, so it can adapt, unlike normal Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) will upload with a percentage completion indicator, but also requires flash.

Answer (score 0):

Try JQuery

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/MultiFile/